# Anteponer menú drop ante tabla

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, y tengo una duda con respecto a anteponer un menú, como lo he visto en otras páginas, dejo como lo tengo.

[image: Como inicia]

---

[image: Como queda el menú]

Básicamente lo que quiero es que ese menú se vea por encima de la tabla, y no deslice la tabla hacía abajo, adicional, me gustaría saber si las propiedades de ese menú las cambio desde el CSS, o las defino en el HTML mediante un STYLE.

Dejo el código.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
                            <ul class="accordion-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="dropdownlink"><i class="fa fa-road" aria-hidden="true"></i>Filtros

                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="submenuItems"> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Abierto ahora</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Open Now</a></li>


                                    </ul>
                                    
                            
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar la tabla y cualquier CSS que hayas intentado

Comment: Decidí usar un estilo diferente de filtro, muchas gracias por el apoyo.